# Key error when setting column width with pyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to set cell width using openpyxl. I'm trying it as follows:

```
 sheet1.column_dimensions['A'].width = 5000.0
```

but it shows the following error:

```
KeyError:'A'
```

How can I specify the column properly?

Answer (score 3):

I'd need all of your code to be sure, but it looks like you *don't actually have any columns to change*.

Try this to debug, right before you are going to change the columns add the following code:

```
for key, value in sheet1.column_dimensions.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

if I am correct nothing will be printed.

---

To answer the next question - why is there nothing there?  I *think* openpyxl only creates the columns once you've told it to.  So if you're trying to do a column manipulation before you changed added any data to the sheet it wont work.  If you do the following first:

```
c = ws.cell(row=i, column=j)
c.value = 'hello world'
```

and then chnage the column width it should work

Comment: Might you have an idea what's the issue here Brad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642026/column-widths-of-some-columns-in-openpyxl-become-zero-after-60-columns