# Column widths (of some columns) in Openpyxl become zero after 60+ columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, excel-2007, openpyxl

Given a `wb` with 5 worksheets, I am adding a column to each every day using `openpyxl`, and this has been working well. Now though, with just over 60 columns, the width of the first N number of columns (seems to be **B** through to **BH**) has become 0. This results in the columns essentially disappearing when opened in Excel:

[image]

Fetching the width of the first few columns confirms this (where `fb` is a `<Worksheet>` object):

```
In [71]: fb.column_dimensions["A"].width
Out[71]: 46.125
In [72]: fb.column_dimensions["B"].width
Out[72]: 0.0
In [73]: fb.column_dimensions["BI"].width
Out[73]: 11.75
In [73]: fb.column_dimensions["BJ"].width
Out[73]: 10.25
```

I've tried setting auto_size:

```
for dimension in fb.column_dimensions.values():
    dimension.auto_size = True
```

and then saving the workbook, but this had no effect (columns are still invisible in Excel). So I tried manually setting the size of a couple of columns to a reasonable size e.g. 12:

```
fb.column_dimensions["B"].width = 12
```

and again saving, but still no change (columns are still invisible in Excel), **despite the fact that when I reload the spreadsheet in openpyxl and check the columns width, they are set to the new (non-zero) size.**

Should either or both of these approaches even have worked, and there is an additional step I'm missing?

Python: 2.7.10

Openpyxl: 2.2.2

Comment: I've gone into Excel, highlighted all cells in one of sheets, then Format->Column->Unhide, and the invisible columns reappear. This initially suggested to me that the issue lay with Excel itself, but if I open the spreadsheet in OpenOffice, the columns are also hidden there.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't seem to be an issue of column widths, but the columns themselves are hidden. Can you post your full code?

A workaround might be `fb.column_dimensions['B'].hidden = False`

Additionally, I would update to the newest version of openpyxl with `pip install openpyxl`

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and setting `.hidden` to `False` does not fix the problem.